# UNIX - Date format for yesterday

Tags: unix, date, format

I know there's some answers elsewhere on this site, and others, but can anyone help me get my date in format **yyyymmdd**, when I use anything I've found on different forums, I just get **yyyymmd**, my script then fails for the first 9 days of the month...

The script I have at the moment uses bash and get the date using

```
date '+%m %d %Y'
```

However, this returns **20120110** for today, but for yesterday it returned **2012019**, I need this to return **201201**0**9**.

Any ideas?

Thanks

P.S. I can't install anything else onto this server, so gnu or perl are out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `date` is actually working fine.

The real problem is that in your bash script (which is in the comments to another answer) you are performing some arithmetic on the resulting values, and the subsequent concatenation of those values loses the leading zeros.

So, in your bash script, after you've calculated the new values of `$YEAR`, `$MONTH` and `$DAY`, use this to get the right output filename:

```
SOURCEFILE=`printf "DNXOUT-%04d%02d%0d2.txt" $YEAR $MONTH $DAY`
```

i.e. just use the `printf` command line executable (which probably does exist) to format the filename.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this just seems to set my SOURCEFILE to "printf "DNXOUT-%04d%02d%0d2.txt" $YEAR $MONTH $DAY"?

Comment: you're missing the backticks, which should _run_ that command and put the output into the variable `SOURCEFILE`.

Comment: D'oh!  Tried it again using `printf "DNXOUT-%04d%02d%02d.txt" $YEAR $MONTH $DAY` and it worked!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried: `date +%Y%m%d`.

```
$ date +%Y%m%d
20120110

$ date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d
20120109
```

Comment: "-d yesterday" returns yesterday's date. It looks like your version of date does not support this flag. But that doesn't matter. I was just trying to demonstrate what would be output if it was yesterday.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't display as yours does, maybe there's a newer version that it works on, but not mine.  Oh well, guess it'll have to be a manual process for the 1st 9 days of the month! :-)

Comment: @dogbane - you need to be aware of the GNU date vs POSIX date issue when you give answers about using date.  Otherwise your answer is fine.

Comment: @Dan - GNU coreturils (Linux usually) has a date command that does date arithmetic.  You do not have it. If you deliberately misuse the date command you can see what options date takes.  Ex date -h  where there is no -h option.  And if there is one you still see what you can use for options.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a POSIX system, the [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/date.html) says that `%d` is for zero-padded day of the month and so `date '+%m %d %Y'` should work, though the format you mention is actually `date '+%Y%m%d'`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the script uses each part to build up the date for yesterday:- date '+%m %d %Y' | { read MONTH DAY YEAR DAY=`expr "$DAY" - 1` case "$DAY" in 0) MONTH=`expr "$MONTH" - 1` case "$MONTH" in 0) MONTH=12 YEAR=`expr "$YEAR" - 1` ;; esac DAY=`cal $MONTH $YEAR | grep . | fmt -1 | tail -1` esac NOW=$YEAR$MONTH$DAY SOURCEFILE="DNXOUT-$NOW.txt"

Comment: Not sure if that makes a difference, but at the moment, it's creating the variable as "DNXOUT-2012019.txt"

Comment: @Dan it's the Bash script calculations to work out "yesterday" that are dropping the leading zero, not the `date` command.

Comment: @Dan they will also fail for the month field on the first of October.

Comment: Is there a better way to work out "yesterday" then?  Other than using "-d yesterday"?

Comment: @Dan it depends - what precise O/S are you running on?

Comment: @Alnitak Just ran uname and apparently it's SunOS.

Answer (score 0):

With the above answers and your remarks it would help to know your platform and the reason you need the date in that format. On the platform, best to have a look at the options of date as listed in the manual `man date` or the build-in help `date -h`.

On the other hand, if your need for the yyyymmdd type date spec is to get a sortable number or name, then you also could use the epoch time: seconds since 1 jan 1970. That also works reasonably nice for doing time calculations. Just add/subtract 3600 for each hour or (3600 * 24) for each day and such. In the end, it is even time-zone and dst safe.

If it helps, I've heard the yyyymmdd (or yyyymmddHHMMSS) way to write a date/time spec is called 'iso', however I might be off here.

Comment: This added nothing than the existing, older answers.